# ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'keras.models'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, densenet

[please open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Lae.png)ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
in cell 12
ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'keras.models' (C:\Users\91626\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\models_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
```

or

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Input
```